# Error: Cursor Finalized without Prior Close

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a Google Map's based application on android.

In short the application works by: first entering some sample data (containing latitude/longitude pairs into a database), reads them and finally plots them on a map overlay.

This app works fine when I run it on Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) emulator as well as on my HTC Desire S.
But when I try the same application in a Android 4.0.3 (ICS) emulator (after making changes in manifest file for sdk version) I get an error `Cursor Finalized without Prior Close()` when I try to execute the activity. With a NullPointer Exception and the app crashes.

**StackTrace pastebin is** [here](http://pastebin.com/6E8PADtx)
**Updated Method(s)**

```
public int getAllEntries() {
        //int entryCount;
        Cursor cursorE = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(LATS) FROM myPROmapData",
                null);
try {
            if (cursorE.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursorE.getInt(0);
            }   
            return cursorE.getInt(0);
            } finally {
              cursorE.close();
            }
    }

--
public Double[] PopulateLats() {

        //id = getAllEntries();

        int LatcolumnIndex = 0;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LATS FROM myPROmapData", null);
        try {
            Double myLats[] = new Double[cursor.getCount()];;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
                    {
                        myLats[i] = cursor.getDouble(LatcolumnIndex);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        //cursor.close();
                    }  

            }   
            return myLats;
            } finally {
              cursor.close();
            }
}

--

public Double[] PopulateLons(){
        int LoncolumnIndex = 0;
        Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT LONS FROM myPROmapData", null);
        try {
            Double myLons[] = new Double[cursor2.getCount()];;
            if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < cursor2.getCount(); i++)
                    {
                        myLons[i] = cursor2.getDouble(LoncolumnIndex);
                        cursor2.moveToNext();
                        //cursor.close();
                    }  

            }   
            return myLons;
            } finally {
              cursor2.close();
            }
}
```

Here's my activity code:

```
public class MapMaster extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private List mapOverlays;
    private Projection projection;
    private MapController mc;
    private MapView mapView;
    private GeoPoint gP;
    // private GeoPoint gP2;
    private MyOverlay myoverlay;
    //Author: Kanishk

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    public Double GetStartLat4gp()
    {   
        Double Lat1 = null;
        db.open();

        //db.insertQuote(); //INSERTING SAMPLE DATA INTO TABLE

        Double[] dtaStartLat = null;
        dtaStartLat = db.PopulateLats();

        for(int z=0;z<(dtaStartLat.length);z++)
        {
            //System.out.println("START_LAT:");
            //System.out.println(dtaStartLat[z]);
            Lat1 = dtaStartLat[z];
            break;
        }
        db.close();
        return Lat1;
    }
    public Double GetStartLon4gp()
    {   
        Double Lon1 = null;
        db.open();

        //db.insertQuote(); //INSERTING SAMPLE DATA INTO TABLE

        Double[] dtaStartLon = null;
        dtaStartLon = db.PopulateLons();

        for(int z=0;z<(dtaStartLon.length);z++)
        {
            //System.out.println("START_LAT:");
            //System.out.println(dtaStartLon[z]);
            Lon1 = dtaStartLon[z];
            break;
        }
        db.close();
        return Lon1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_master);
        //Double myStartLat = null;
        //Double myStartLon = null;

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);// Creating an instance
                                                        // of MapView
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);// Enabling the built-in Zoom
                                                // Controls

        //mapView.setTraffic(true);
        //mapView.setStreetView(true);

        GeoPoint gP = new GeoPoint((int)(GetStartLat4gp() * 1E6), (int)(GetStartLon4gp() * 1E6));
        //gP = new GeoPoint(28570000, 77320000);// Creating a GeoPoint

        System.out.println("v START CORDS v");
        System.out.println(GetStartLat4gp());
        System.out.println(GetStartLon4gp());
        System.out.println("^ START CORDS ^");

        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setCenter(gP);

        mc.setZoom(15);// Initializing the MapController and setting the map to
                        // center at the
        // defined GeoPoint

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        projection = mapView.getProjection();

        myoverlay = new MyOverlay();
        mapOverlays.add(myoverlay);

        db.open();

        //db.CreateSampleData();  //create sample data
        //db.SyncNclean();      //SYNC - CLEAN

        if(db.doesDatabaseExist(this, "PROdb")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.SyncNclean();
            Toast.makeText(this, "CLEANING..CREATING SAMPLE DATA..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.CreateSampleData();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sample Data Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "DOES NOT EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.SyncNclean();
            Toast.makeText(this, "CLEANING..CREATING SAMPLE DATA..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.CreateSampleData();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sample Data Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


        long id = 0;
        id = db.getAllEntries();
        CharSequence text = "The data was added successfully!\nData Totals = " + id + "Records";
        System.out.println(text);
        db.close();
    }
    public Double[] GetLats()
    {   
        db.open();

        //db.insertQuote(); //INSERTING SAMPLE DATA INTO TABLE

        Double[] dtaMyLats = null;
        dtaMyLats = db.PopulateLats();
        for(int z=0;z<(dtaMyLats.length);z++)
        {
            System.out.println("LATS:");
            System.out.println(dtaMyLats[z]);
        }
        db.close();
        return dtaMyLats;
    }
    public Double[] GetLons()
    {
        db.open();
        Double[] dtaMyLons = null;
        dtaMyLons = db.PopulateLons();
        for(int z=0;z<(dtaMyLons.length);z++)
        {
            System.out.println("LONS:");
            System.out.println(dtaMyLons[z]);
        }
        db.close();
        return dtaMyLons;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    class MyOverlay extends Overlay {

        public MyOverlay() {

        }
        //Author: Kanishk



        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);
            // Configuring the paint brush
            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);


            Double[] LatArr = GetLats();
            Double[] LonArr = GetLons();


        //generate geopoints dynamically based on coordinates from index @ array
            //author: Kanishk

            int count = LatArr.length;
            //System.out.println(count);

            for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++)
            {

                    Double lat1;
                    Double lon1;
                    Double lat2;
                    Double lon2;
                    lat1 = LatArr[i];
                    lon1 = LonArr[i];
                    //System.out.println(LatLon[i][j]);
                    /*System.out.println("<< BREAK >>");
                    System.out.println(lat1);
                    System.out.println(lon1);
                    */
                    lat2=LatArr[i+1];
                    //lat1 = null;
                    lon2=LonArr[i+1];
                    //lon1 = null;
                    //i++;

                    if(lat2!=null){
                    GeoPoint gp1 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat1 * 1E6), (int)(lon1 * 1E6)); //
                    GeoPoint gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat2 * 1E6), (int)(lon2 * 1E6)); //
                    System.out.println("<< coord1 >>");
                    System.out.println(lat1);
                    System.out.println(lon1);
                    System.out.println("<< coord2 >>");
                    System.out.println(lat2);
                    System.out.println(lon2);

                    Point p11 = new Point();
                    Point p22 = new Point();

                    Path mypath = new Path();
                    projection.toPixels(gp1, p11);
                    projection.toPixels(gp2, p22);
                    mypath.moveTo(p22.x, p22.y);// *
                    mypath.lineTo(p11.x, p11.y);// *

                    canvas.drawPath(mypath, mPaint);
                    }


            }
        // logic end

        }

    }
}
```

DBAdapter Class:

```
public class DBAdapter {
    int id = 0;
    //public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_PHID = "phID";
    public String KEY_LAT = "LATS";
    public String KEY_LON = "LONS";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PROdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "myPROmapData";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;

    //private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table myPROmapData (_id integer primary key autoincrement, phID integer, LATS real not null, LONS real not null);";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table myPROmapData (phID integer, LATS real not null, LONS real not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,"Error: onCreate db");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myPROmapData");
            onCreate(db);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,"Error: onUpgrade db");
            }
        }
    }

    // ---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // ---closes the database---
    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // ---insert sample data into the database---
    public long CreateSampleData() {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHID, 100);

        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4588);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0725);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4719);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0722);
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);


        /*initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.5700);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.3200);*/
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4795);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0800);
         db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        /*initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4700);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0300);*/
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4813);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.0931);
         db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        /*initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 27.1833);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 78.0167);*/
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4820);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.1023);
         db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        /*initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 26.4583);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 80.3173);*/
        initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, 28.4804);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LON, 77.1251);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public int getAllEntries() {
        //int entryCount;
        Cursor cursorE = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(LATS) FROM myPROmapData",
                null);
        if (cursorE.moveToFirst()) {
            //entryCount = cursorE.getInt(0);
            return cursorE.getInt(0);
            //return entryCount;
        }
                        //  CLOSING CURSOR
        cursorE.close(); 
        return cursorE.getInt(0);

        //return entryCount;
    }

    public boolean doesDatabaseExist(ContextWrapper context, String dbName) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);

        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    public void SyncNclean(){

        Log.w(TAG, "Sync'ing with Master Server..");

        //sync master server here

        Log.w(TAG, "Sync Complete..");
        //Log.w(TAG, "Cleaning old data..");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myPROmapData");
        DBHelper.onCreate(db);

        Log.w(TAG, "Cleaning completed..");
    }

    public Double[] PopulateLats() {

        //id = getAllEntries();

        int LatcolumnIndex = 0;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LATS FROM myPROmapData", null);
        Double myLats[] = new Double[cursor.getCount()];;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {                       
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
            {
                myLats[i] = cursor.getDouble(LatcolumnIndex);
                cursor.moveToNext();
                cursor.close();
            }  

        }
        // Original location for cursor.close()

        return myLats;

    }

    public Double[] PopulateLons(){
        int LoncolumnIndex = 0;
        Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT LONS FROM myPROmapData", null);
        Double myLons[] = new Double[cursor2.getCount()];;
        if (cursor2.moveToFirst())
        {                       
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor2.getCount(); i++)
            {
                myLons[i] = cursor2.getDouble(LoncolumnIndex);
                cursor2.moveToNext();
                cursor2.close(); //third try
            }
            // second tried here: cursor2.close();
        }
        // Original location for cursor.close()
        //db.close();

        return myLons;
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Looking at google results for your error message, i think the cursor warning is independent from the NPE - where does the NPE occur, what is the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, Please see the updated ques for stacktrace. (http://pastebin.com/6E8PADtx)

Comment: so the NPE occurs in onCreate() of MapMaster, line 89. What line is that?

Comment: @DThought Line89: `GeoPoint gP = new GeoPoint((int)(GetStartLat4gp() * 1E6), (int)(GetStartLon4gp() * 1E6));` The method `GetStartLat4gp` & `GetStartLon4gp` use values returned from Populate methods

Comment: i strongly guess, the GetStartLat4gp or GetStartLon4gp returns null.

You create the sample data at the end of the onCreate method , but use it (with getStartLat4gp) at the beginning. Move the db creation to top

Comment: @DThought Earlier today I was getting an NPE (NullPointerException). Thanks to the careful observation, your comment saved me. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to the nullpointer exception is:

GetStartLat4gp or GetStartLon4gp returns null.

Apart from that, the code will be more stable whenn you rewrite this method to

```
public int getAllEntries() {
    //int entryCount;
    Cursor cursorE = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(LATS) FROM myPROmapData",
            null);
    try {
      if (cursorE.moveToFirst()) {
          return cursorE.getInt(0);
      }   
      return cursorE.getInt(0);
    } finally {
      cursorE.close();
    }
}
```

In the original draft of it, it did not close the cursor because it did return early.

use try {} finally { close resources } as a good style, to be sure to close all resources in any case (even unexpected exceptions)

Apart from that, move the close() of the other cursor back outside the loop, it will provoke errors inside the loop.  (best, use try / finally there, too)

Comment: Nope..still getting the same error with NPE. I changed all 3 of my methods carefully. Please see my updated question having the updated method(s) code. btw Thanks for replying first :)

Comment: Also, I am getting this warning/error (Cursor Finalized without prior close()) 2 times..so I guess the Populate methods are the defaulters.

Comment: Thanks DThought, that did it! :) Please edit your answer to include: The GetStartLat4gp or GetStartLon4gp returns null. Sample data is created at the end of the onCreate method , but is used it (with getStartLat4gp) at the beginning. Moving the db creation to top will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because your doing a return statement before the finally so in this case the finally never gets executed and therefore the database doesn't get closed

You should move get the value from the cursor and set it to a variable and then return the variable at the bottom of the function like below.

```
public int getAllEntries() {
    //int entryCount;
    Cursor cursorE = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(LATS) FROM myPROmapData",
            null);
    int value = 0
    try {
      if (cursorE.moveToFirst()) {
          value = cursorE.getInt(0);
      }   
      value = cursorE.getInt(0);
    } finally {
      cursorE.close();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Also as a side line comment your db.rawQuey should also be within the the try statement otherwise if the query fails for whatever reason the app will force close.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I will be moving all the database queries into a try catch/try catch finally block.